# How to access database using phone gap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am new to android phonegap. i am storing and retrieving data using native application. i dont know how to display the retrieved data from native to phonegap(HTML)page.

can anyone pls guide me how to access sqlite with phonegap.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saving the data through native android coding? And do you want to retrieve values(stored in sqlite) from phonegap?

Comment: Yes, i m saving data through native, and want to retrieve via phonegap.

Comment: Are you saving data through a service or some thing which is packaged along with this phonegap & then you want to retrieve it via phonegap?

Comment: actually its not a service oriented. i roughly wrote native to store the data. and accessing data through phone gap. is it possible to get sqlite db using phonegap..??

Comment: Yes It is Possible to access the database from phonegap which is stored at /data/data/package-name/databases/*.db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create a Android plugin for Phonegap through which you will be able to access the native code and hence the native DB like this

```
public class SqlitePlugin extends Plugin {

private static final String TAG = "SqlitePlugin";
private static final String CREATE_DB_ACTION = "createDatabase";
private static final String SHOW_DB_VALUES_ACTION = "showValues";

@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Plugin Called");
    PluginResult result = null;

    if (CREATE_DB_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CREATE_DB_ACTION");
        DB _db = new DB(ctx);
        _db.insertValues();
    }
    else if (SHOW_DB_VALUES_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SHOW_DB_VALUES_ACTION");

        JSONObject DBInfo = null;
        try {
            DBInfo = getDBValuesListing();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, DBInfo);

    }       
    else {
        result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action : " + action + " passed");
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

After that Create a sqlite.js file like this

```
    function SqlitePlugin() {
};

SqlitePlugin.prototype.createDatabase = function(successCallback, failCallback) {

return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failCallback, "SqlitePlugin",
        "createDatabase", [ null ]);
};

SqlitePlugin.prototype.showValues = function(params, successCallback, failCallback) {
return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failCallback, 'SqlitePlugin', 'showValues',
        [ params ]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
PhoneGap.addPlugin("SqlitePlugin", new SqlitePlugin());
});
```

Import this sqlite.js in your page(index.html) and then finally use the plugin like this

```
function showValues() {
    window.plugins.SqlitePlugin.showValues('showValues',
            showValuesSuccessCallBack, showValuesFailCallBack);

}
function showValuesSuccessCallBack(e) {
    if (e.Rows.length > 0) {
        alert("Success");
        for (i = 0; i < e.Rows.length; i++) {
            alert("Id = " + e.Rows[i].id);
            alert("Number = " + e.Rows[i].number);
        }
    } else {
        alert("No values in Database");
    }
}

function showValuesFailCallBack(f) {
    alert("Failure");
}
```

Let me know if this worked out for you

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am still having doubt, what you mentioned here CREATE_DB_ACTION & SHOW_DB_VALUES_ACTION. wther its a database name or something else. and thanks once again.

Comment: See this CREATE_DB_ACTION & SHOW_DB_VALUES_ACTION are basically operationswhich you specify in your sqlite.js file.Like suppose currently in our index.html page we have used window.plugins.SqlitePlugin.showValues,this specifies that you are going to perform 'showValues' action and hence you can catch this event in sqliteplugin..So you can code there..:)

Answer (score 0):

Write an phonegap plugin to pass the data from native side to html (js)
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android

Comment: Thanku. but can you guide me on how to connect the native sqllite with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably should use the HTML5 functions to store and retrieve data from a sqlite DB. However, if you are set on doing it with native code you should look at our implementation which was used for older Android devices that don't support sqlite.

https://github.com/cordova/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/assets/js/storage.js
https://github.com/cordova/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/com/phonegap/Storage.java